# Python 3.3 no module named MySQLdb, cymysql installed

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Working through the introductory Django project tutorial on the official site. I have successfully installed the CyMySQL 0.5.5 connector through pip. The server status is "Running". For the command `python manage.py syncdb` this is what powershell returns. Could this have something to do with the DATABASES section of `settings.py` file having wrong parameters? :

```
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py:39: DeprecationWarning: imp.get_suffixes() is deprecated; use
constants defined on importlib.machinery instead
  for suffix_item in imp.get_suffixes():

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 584, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1022, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1003, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_for_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 868, in _load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use django-cymysql and latest cymysql

djang-cymysql https://github.com/nakagami/django-cymysql/

cymysql 0.7.2 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cymysql/0.7.2

and use 'mysql_cymysql' ENGINE

Comment: Thank you! I will try that out when I get a chance. Right now I have kind of given up and switched back to 2.7.